# Gnome Metacity and GuestSession

Tags: 16.04, guest-session, metacity

I would like a guest session to use *by default* Gnome Metacity instead of the default Ubuntu window manager (I use Ubuntu 16.04). Where are the configuration files ?

Answer (score 1):

Details about customizing the guest session can be found here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession

I would suppose that the "Special purpose user" section would be useful for you.

Comment: I still have no clue how to modify the default window manager.

Comment: @PhilippeGaucher: Probably you need to use metacity systemwide, and not only in guest sessions. The page I pointed to shows how to adapt the user configuration for guest session to your liking, but the window manager is used system wide. Sorry, I should have realized that.

Comment: I always use Gnome Metacity (I never managed to get used with Gnome 3.0 :-)). The best would be to get rid of the Ubuntu window manager, but I can't remove the packages without breaking other things. Hopefully that will be possible with the next LTS version. Thanks for answering anyway.

Comment: @PhilippeGaucher: I see. If the regular user sessions use metacity, I'd expect the guest session to do it as well. Tried GNOME Flashback?